# Is there a standalone Python type conversion library?

Tags: python, type-conversion

Are there any standalone type conversion libraries?

I have a data storage system that only understands bytes/strings, but I can tag metadata such as the type to be converted to.

I could hack up some naive system of type converters, as every other application has done before me, or I could hopefully use a standalone library, except I can't find one. Odd for such a common activity.

Just to clarify, I will have something like:

('123', 'integer') and I want to get out 123

Comment: Python has very few types, sting, int, float are about it.  You have built-in conversions ("str", "int", "float").  What more do you need than these three functions?  Please be specific.

Comment: S. Lott: those really are all that I need. But a well-tested, error-resilient library to do it would be nice.

Comment: @Ali A: You already have the three functions.  That is the well-tested, error-resilient library.  What more do you want?  Please be specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flatland does this well. http://discorporate.us/projects/flatland/

Comment: This is a much better solution than the hacks I had previously accepted. The fact that this exists even proves that the question is worthwhile, not -1 as it is currently voted.

Answer (score 3):

You've got two options, either use the [struct](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html#module-struct) or [pickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#module-pickle) modules.

With struct you specify a format and it compacts your data to byte array. This is useful for working with C structures or writing to networked apps that require are binary protocol.

pickle can automatically serialise and deserialise complex Python structures to a string. There are some caveats so it's best read the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#module-pickle). I think this is the most likely the library you want.

```
>>> import pickle
>>> v = pickle.dumps(123)
>>> v
'I123\n.'
>>> pickle.loads(v)
123
>>> v = pickle.dumps({"abc": 123})
>>> v
"(dp0\nS'abc'\np1\nI123\ns."
>>> pickle.loads(v)
{'abc': 123}
```

Comment: Pickle won't do it, the format already exists in the database, and if I store pickles I lose the db's querying abilities. Struct could work though.

Answer (score 3):

Consider this.

```
import datetime

def toDate( someString ):
    return datetime.datetime.strptime( someString, "%x" ).date()

typeConversionMapping = { 'integer': int, 'string': str, 'float': float, 'date': toDate }
def typeConversionFunction( typeConversionTuple ):
    theStringRepresentation, theTypeName = typeConversionTuple
    return typeConversionMapping[theTypeName](theStringRepresentation)
```

Is that a good enough standalone library for such a common activity?  Would that be enough of a well-tested, error-resilient library?  Or is there something more that's required?

If you need more or different date/time conversions, you simply add new `toDate` functions with different formats.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but that would break on passing 'abc' as an integer

Comment: @Ali A: Shouldn't it break?  'abc' isn't an integer.

Comment: @Ali A: It throws an exception: TypeError.  That's what is designed to happen.  Is there something more that's required?  Be specific.

Comment: Accepting, though I think the answer to the question is "no". These simple ones are great, but then you will get to dates/times etc.

Comment: @Ali A.  Dates and times are NEVER simple conversions because of the formatting issues.   However, they're trivial to add to this example.

Comment: @Ali A.  The answer remains "yes".  There are standard conversions for all Python types.  They're all there.  Already defined.  Already part of the language or libraries.

Comment: S.Lott: You are actually illustrating my point, that since it is so apparently simple, naive implementations exist everywhere. It's not part of the language, it's easily doable with the language.

Comment: @Ali A: I can't understand the distinctions between no part of the language and easily doable with the language and whatever it is you want that's different from this.